# Split xml file, aggregate based on headeras correlation key and create multiple files with the correlation key as fileName

Tags: apache-camel

I need to split an xml file, and then aggregate elements with similar DeptId into separate files with the DeptId as filename.

```
<Records>
    <Entry>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>John Smith</Name>
        <DeptId>1</DeptId>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Mike Nash</Name>
        <DeptId>3</DeptId>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
        <DeptId>3</DeptId>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Name>Jack Ryan</Name>
        <DeptId>1</DeptId>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Name>Mike Jordan</Name>
        <DeptId>1</DeptId>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <Name>Chris Evans</Name>
        <DeptId>2</DeptId>
    </Entry>
</Records>
```

This is my route:

```
from("file:inbox")
    .split().tokenizeXML("Entry")
    .setHeader("deptid").xpath("Entry/DeptId", String.class)
    .log("${header.deptid}")
    .log("Sending ${body} with correlation key ${header.deptid}")
    .aggregate(header("deptid"), new HeaderAggregator())
        .completionPredicate(exchangeProperty(Exchange.SPLIT_COMPLETE).isEqualTo(true))
        .log("sending out ${body}")
        .to("file:outbox?fileName=${header.deptid}.txt")
    .end()
.end();
```

I am getting only one file out for DeptId 2.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The split complete message will only happens once. When the entire XML file has been run through the spliter. Thus you only see one file which probably is the last item in the split.

Comment: how should I setup the completionpredicate in this case?

Comment: In your case you would need to know exactly how many lines per group. For example there are 5 lines that go to group A etc. There could be other ways but I really dont know the data well enough to suggest anything else.